# Unable to cast object of type Castle.Proxies.INavigationServiceProxy to Prism.Common.IPageaware

Tags: xamarin, prism

I have been using a mock of INavigationService in order to conduct some unit tests and I get an error when the application tries to verify the current URI path. The line of code that verifies this is the following:

```
if (_navigationService.GetNavigationUriPath().Contains("Register"))
                RegisterFlag = true;
```

And here is the mock of the INavigationService:

```
Mock<INavigationService> _navServ;
...
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            Properties.Api = new MockService();
            _navServ = new Mock<INavigationService>();
        }
```

When i debug any of my tests i get the error "Unable to cast object of type Castle.Proxies.INavigationServiceProxy to Prism.Common.IPageaware" on the first line of code i present.
I would like to understand why this happens and what I can do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/5b5c54ae2af12144736d88c6a2fa2fdc7faf8a7f/src/Forms/Prism.Forms/Navigation/INavigationServiceExtensions.cs#L46) of `GetNavigationUriPath` (which you should really have done, as the stack trace of the exceptions points to it), you see that you have to setup the `Page`-property of your navigation-service mock (see the [docs of moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#advanced-features)):

```
_navServ = new Mock<INavigationService>();
_navServ.As<IPageAware>().Setup( x => x.Page ).Returns( /* your current page */ );
```

Comment: I read a bit of the documentation on the GetNavigationUriPath but had no idea I could pass it as IPageAware. Thank you so much!